# Notepad++ Delete all lines with more than 1 Colon

Tags: regex, notepad++

I would like to delete all lines from my large text file which have more than one colon.

An explanation of how the code works would also be much appreciated.

**Example:**

```
yes:no:no
yes:no
yes:no
no:yes
yes:yes:no
```

**What I want:**

```
yes:no
yes:no
no:yes
```

So it deletes the first and last lines because they had more than 1 colon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

<kbd>CTRL+H</kbd>

**Find:**

```
.*:.*:.*\r\n
```

**Replace:**
    (enter nothing)

Note that I am assuming Windows line endings here (`\r\n`).  If you are running on Unix then you would just use `\n` as the line ending, so the regex would be:

```
.*:.*:.*\n
```

Here is a screen capture for reference:

[image]

Comment: Thanks man! It worked!

Comment: or use `(\r\n|\r|\n)` for a platform independent line ending.